# How to select values ​from a column with a specific word followed by a random number

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to get all values from a table where in a column appears the text 'demo' followed a number.

My database is Oracle.

```
ID    NAME
------------
1     demo20
2     demo26
3     demo
4     any
```

I just need the values ​​with the demo word with a number. At the moment I have this:

```
select * from table where NAME like 'demo';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the names that start with the sub-string `demo` and have at least one following character using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  name LIKE 'demo_%'
```

If you want to find `demo` followed by only trailing numbers then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  name LIKE 'demo_%'
AND    VALIDATE_CONVERSION(SUBSTR(name, 5) AS NUMBER) = 1;
```

or, in most versions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^demo\d+$');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name) AS
SELECT 'demo20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'demo26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'demo2a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'demo'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'any'    FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| NAME |
| --- |
| demo20 |
| demo26 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BywGI6Jy)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The three queries work. I'm using REGEXP_LIKE :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [REGEXP_LIKE](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4490011/using-regexp-like):

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^demo\d');
```

Test here: https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle19/4284f904af9157489dc4a0c9d9515c7c/

```
+====+========+
| ID | NAME   |
+====+========+
| 1  | demo20 |
| 2  | demo26 |
+----+--------+
```

When you need to filter strings that do not contain additional characters after digits, you can use the following:

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^demo\d+$');
```

Comment: @Kane This would match `demo2not_a_number` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KXHJ_1nO)

Comment: It doesn't affect my data. The final characters ​​are only numeric :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'n not understand that from your original question, but you can use https://sqlize.online/s/ot